# By-pass bootin Ubuntu to desktop

Tags: boot

Well, I have a question and I try to explain what is my problem:-)

So...

Is it possible, somehow, instead of booting Ubuntu in desktop, boot Ubuntu in some program - but not using Autostart option ?

I'm heavy user of Aranym, an Atari virtual machine, and I need Ubuntu to boot directly to Aranym, without seeing GUI/Desktop, something like when you change default shell in Windows and instead of Exlporer run some other shell/custom desktop.

Please note that I'm some relatively new Ubuntu user and detailed instructions or link to useful information how can I do this thing will be really helpful:-)

With best regards to all !
Nagual